How to design a simple calculator in Logicim?
I want to design a simple calculator in Logicim program that performs four basic operations, takes two four-bit numbers as input and presents the output as an 8-bit number.
I tried different ways to draw the circuit in the program, but I didn't manage to execute it well, but I think we need to use the double dabble algorithm or ROM block to display our 8-bit number on the screen.
